# How to change pip base URL back to pypi.org?

Tags: python, windows, pip

In my windows10 python 3.4 installation pip tries to access our corporate `~\simple` base url.  I have purposely disconnected from the `vpn` to force it to access `pypi.org` but I keep getting `"Cannot fetch index base URL http://<company location>.com:8085/simple/"` .  This happens both inside and outside a virtual environment.  One suggestion was to locate and edit `pip.ini` but it doesn't exist in the installation.

How do I change the base URL to point to `pypi.org`?

Comment: Could you search the file system for any file called `pip.ini`?

Comment: I did a whereis pip.ini and several locations were provided for pip only.   Nothing for pip.ini .

Comment: Found it in c:\ProgramData\pip and in c:\Users\All Users\pip. Both have the problematic index-url entry.  Which location has the pip.ini file that is most relevant?